# Generating XML reports using LINQ to XML in C#

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I'm generating reports using LINQ to XML in C#.
For example, I want to generate a report formatted like:

```
<report>
    <canada>
        <division_1>
            <power generated="22" dailygoal="25" />
            <resources used="15" available="50" />
        </division_1>
        <division_2>
            <power generated="36" dailygoal="40" />
            <resources used="28" available="85" />
        </division_2>
    </canada>
</report>
```

How can I generate an XML file (with one root element) with this format in C# by using foreach loops and object methods to fill the data like so, since I'm getting the data from power and resources objects?:

```
foreach (var i in powerList)
{
    division_1.Add(
        new XElement("power",
            new XAttribute("generated", i.powerGenerated),
            new XAttribute("dailygoal", i.powerGoal)),
        new XElement("resources",
            new XAttribute("used", i.resourcesUsed),
            new XAttribute("available", i.resourcesAvailable)));
{
```

Can I do this with an XDocument object, or do I need to initialize division_1 and division_2 as XElements, do .Add to add the info to the XElements, .Save the XElements as .xml docs, then merge and save them as one doc?

**Update:**

I've modified the code to look like this...:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        // list of power objects...

        List<Power> powerList = new List<Power>();

        Power canada = new Power("canada", 25, 50, 70, 100);
        Power usa = new Power("usa", 45, 60, 80, 150);
        Power sweden = new Power("sweden", 50, 60, 70, 80);
        Power germany = new Power("germany", 65, 75, 90, 125);

        powerList.Add(canada);
        powerList.Add(usa);
        powerList.Add(sweden);
        powerList.Add(germany);

        // create report var and element..

        var report = new XElement("report");

        // foreach...
        foreach (var x in powerList)
        {

            var country = new XElement(x.Country);
            report.Add(country);

            var n = 0;

            //foreach...
            foreach (var i in powerList)
            {
                ++n;

                var division = new XElement("division_" + n);

                division.Add(
                    new XElement("power",
                        new XAttribute("generated", i.powerGenerated),
                        new XAttribute("dailygoal", i.powerGoal)),
                    new XElement("resources",
                        new XAttribute("used", i.resourcesUsed),
                        new XAttribute("available", i.resourcesAvailable)));
                country.Add(division);
            }
        }

        // create xdocument from xelement and save to disk...

        XDocument xml = new XDocument();
        xml.Add(report);

        xml.Save(@".\report.xml");
    }
}
}
```

... but it's generating, for example:

```
<canada>
    <division_1>
        <power generated="25" dailygoal="50" />
        <resources used="70" available="100" />
    </division_1>
    <division_2>
        <power generated="45" dailygoal="60" />
        <resources used="80" available="150" />
    </division_2>
    <division_3>
        <power generated="50" dailygoal="60" />
        <resources used="70" available="80" />
    </division_3>
    <division_4>
        <power generated="65" dailygoal="75" />
        <resources used="90" available="125" />
    </division_4>
</canada>
<usa>
    <division_1>
        <power generated="25" dailygoal="50" />
        <resources used="70" available="100" />
    </division_1>
    <division_2>
        <power generated="45" dailygoal="60" />
        <resources used="80" available="150" />
    </division_2>
    <division_3>
        <power generated="50" dailygoal="60" />
        <resources used="70" available="80" />
    </division_3>
    <division_4>
        <power generated="65" dailygoal="75" />
        <resources used="90" available="125" />
    </division_4>
</usa>
```

In the loop it's generating the same data for all objects each run through. Do you see what the issue is and how it could be fixed? I've tried multiple approaches and can't seem to get it.

Comment: What problem do you have? Describe your actual results or add error details if you have error

Comment: What problem do you have? You didn't add any problem details

Comment: UPDATE: In your original, you had two Power objects for Canada, hence the need for the inner loop.  Your revised version has one Power object  per country (which eliminates the need for the "division" layer)

Comment: Is there a way to keep the Power class how it is and keep multiple divisions, or would I have to change Power to not take a country name and have a different list/class for countries so it doesn't print a country every loop? Because I do need to keep multiple divisions per country.

Comment: You don't need inner for each statement in your code use the variable x to fetch power and resources related data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to do what you are looking for:

```
var powerList = new PowerList[] {
    new PowerList { powerGenerated = 22, powerGoal = 25, resourcesUsed = 15, resourcesAvailable = 50 },
    new PowerList { powerGenerated = 36, powerGoal = 40, resourcesUsed = 28, resourcesAvailable = 85 }
};

var report = new XElement("report");
var country = new XElement("canada");
report.Add(country);

var n = 0;
foreach (var i in powerList)
{
    ++n;
    var division = new XElement("division_"+n);

    division.Add(
        new XElement("power",
            new XAttribute("generated", i.powerGenerated),
            new XAttribute("dailygoal", i.powerGoal)),
        new XElement("resources",
            new XAttribute("used", i.resourcesUsed),
            new XAttribute("available", i.resourcesAvailable)));
    country.Add(division);
}

XDocument xml = new XDocument();
xml.Add(report);
```

Comment: That's definitely on the right track, but what if I wanted to add "usa" as another country with the same elements? How would I combine the two elements under the same root and save?

Comment: I planned for that (which is why the XElement is called `country` and not `canada`).  Just add another foreach loop, starting between the `var report=` and the `var country=`  and ending just before the `XDocument xml`

Comment: Right, I see. That's perfect. Appreciate the help!

Comment: I've added an update to my original post because I'm having a little issue. Would you mind taking a look? Thanks @James Curran

Answer (score 0):

Yes you could use `XElement`:

```
  var root = new XElement("report");
  var canada=new XElement("canada");
  root.Add(canada);
  for(int i=0;i<powerList.Count();i++)
  { 
        canada.Add(new XElement("division"+(i+1).ToString(),
        new XElement("power",
            new XAttribute("generated", powerList[i].powerGenerated),
            new XAttribute("dailygoal", powerList[i].powerGoal)),
        new XElement("resources",
            new XAttribute("used", powerList[i].resourcesUsed),
            new XAttribute("available", powerList[i].resourcesAvailable))));
  }
  root.Save("Root.xml");
```

`XElement` has a [`Save`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360171(v=vs.110).aspx) method.